# How to use BeginInvoke C#

Tags: c#, begininvoke

Could you explain this for me please:

```
someformobj.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
{
    someformobj.listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}));
```

Could you tell me how can I use `begininvoke` exactly?
What is `Action` type?
Why there is blank brackets `()`?
And what does this mean `=>`?

Comment: so many different questions in one post... - there should be at least 3 separate questions

Comment: Take a look at this article as well http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com.uy/2014/07/six-ways-to-initiate-tasks-on-another.html

Answer (score 91, accepted):

[`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) is a Type of Delegate provided by the .NET framework.  The `Action` points to a method with no parameters and does not return a value.

`() =>` is [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) syntax.  Lambda expressions are not of Type `Delegate`.  Invoke requires `Delegate` so `Action` can be used to wrap the lambda expression and provide the expected `Type` to `Invoke()`

`Invoke` causes said `Action` to execute on the thread that created the Control's window handle.  Changing threads is often necessary to avoid `Exceptions`.  For example, if one tries to set the `Rtf` property on a `RichTextBox` when an Invoke is necessary, without first calling Invoke, then a `Cross-thread operation not valid` exception will be thrown.  Check `Control.InvokeRequired` before calling Invoke.

`BeginInvoke` is the Asynchronous version of `Invoke`.  Asynchronous means the thread will not block the caller as opposed to a synchronous call which is blocking.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, Action is used to guarantee cross-thread safety, so you would inform the object via the method call instead of setting the value yourself?

Also, the method will accept ANY delegate, not just an Action specifically, yes?

Comment: @KyleBaran - `Action` is unrelated to thread safety, that's `Invoke`.  `Invoke` accepts a `Delegate` as a parameter.  So anything convertible to a `Delegate` can be passed as a parameter.

Comment: @KyleBaran Action is just a built-in delegate type, you can just replace it with:
delegate void mydlg();
 Invoke((mydlg)(() =>
                {
                }));

Answer (score 15):

I guess your code relates to Windows Forms.
You call `BeginInvoke` if you need something to be executed asynchronously in the UI thread: change control's properties in most of the cases.
Roughly speaking this is accomplished be passing the delegate to some procedure which is being periodically executed. (message loop processing and the stuff like that)

If `BeginInvoke` is called for `Delegate` type the delegate is just invoked asynchronously.
(`Invoke` for the sync version.)

If you want more universal code which works perfectly for WPF and WinForms you can consider Task Parallel Library and running the `Task` with the according [context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx). (`TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`)

And to add a little to already said by others:
Lambdas can be treated either as anonymous methods or [expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx).
And that is why you cannot just use `var` with lambdas: compiler needs a hint.

**UPDATE:**

this requires .Net v4.0 and higher

```
// This line must be called in UI thread to get correct scheduler
var scheduler = System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

// this can be called anywhere
var task = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task( () => someformobj.listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0);

// also can be called anywhere. Task  will be scheduled for execution.
// And *IF I'm not mistaken* can be (or even will be executed synchronously)
// if this call is made from GUI thread. (to be checked) 
task.Start(scheduler);
```

If you started the task from other thread and need to wait for its completition `task.Wait()` will block calling thread till the end of the task.

Read more about tasks [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx).

Comment: could u give me some examples please ?