# How to update some GUI control in a WinForm from another thread in C# using async

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'm trying to update the text of some GUI controls from a second thread but Visual Studio shows an exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information:

> Invalid operation through sub-processes: access to 'impPROF_combo' took control from a other thread than that in which he created .

---

My code is:

```cs
    private async void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        sciLoadingCircle1.Visible = true;
        sciLoadingCircle1.Active = true;

        await Task.Run(() => refreshComboColumnsNames());

        sciLoadingCircle1.Visible = false;
        sciLoadingCircle1.Active = false;

    }
    private void refreshComboColumnsNames()
    {
        object[] columnsNames = this.generateComboColumnsNames();
        int impPROF_combo_selected = impPROF_combo.SelectedIndex; //the exceptions  throws from here 
        impPROF_combo.Items.Clear();

        impPROF_combo.Items.AddRange(columnsNames);

        impPROF_combo.SelectedIndex = impPROF_combo_selected;
    }
```

How I can do this the right way?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to change the second method,s signature to `private async Task refreshComboColumnsNames()` and call it within the first method like this: `await refreshComboColumnsNames();`?

Comment: `generateComboColumnsNames()` can be done in another thread (if it takes a long time?), but updating the actual controls needs to happen in the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

UI components should only be accessed from their UI thread. In this case, you're putting too much code in the `Task.Run`:

```
private async void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  sciLoadingCircle1.Visible = true;
  sciLoadingCircle1.Active = true;

  await refreshComboColumnsNamesAsync();

  sciLoadingCircle1.Visible = false;
  sciLoadingCircle1.Active = false;
}

private async Task refreshComboColumnsNamesAsync()
{
  object[] columnsNames = await Task.Run(() => this.generateComboColumnsNames());
  int impPROF_combo_selected = impPROF_combo.SelectedIndex;
  impPROF_combo.Items.Clear();
  impPROF_combo.Items.AddRange(columnsNames);
  impPROF_combo.SelectedIndex = impPROF_combo_selected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to update GUI (or use) elements from another thread you should use Control.BeginInvoke() https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx 
And here is how to use it.
[How to use BeginInvoke C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388136/how-to-use-begininvoke-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Usual reason why you want to execute some code in a thread other than GUI thread is that the operation takes to much time to finish and blocks GUI thread.

I can see in `refreshComboColumnsNames` method the only line of code, which can potentially take time - `generateComboColumnsNames`. Other statements are GUI update operations, which have to be executed in GUI thread. As I understand, `generateComboColumnsNames` does some heavy calculations or executes db query or sends http request or does any other long operations. Result of this operation needs to be displayed in UI. Correct me, if I am wrong.

I would suggest to make `generateComboColumnsNames` async operating, which is executed in separate thread. This operation must not update UI - just return data.
Result will look like next:

```
private async void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sciLoadingCircle1.Visible = true;
    sciLoadingCircle1.Active = true;

    await refreshComboColumnsNames();

    sciLoadingCircle1.Visible = false;
    sciLoadingCircle1.Active = false;

}

private async Task refreshComboColumnsNames()
{
    object[] columnsNames = await this.generateComboColumnsNames();

    int impPROF_combo_selected = impPROF_combo.SelectedIndex;             
    impPROF_combo.Items.Clear();
    impPROF_combo.Items.AddRange(columnsNames);
    impPROF_combo.SelectedIndex = impPROF_combo_selected;
}
```