# How to use BeginInvoke in VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, begininvoke

In C# you use `BeginInvoke` like this:

```
obj.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
{
    //do something
}));
```

I tried to translate it to VB.NET, and ended up with this code, that seems to work:

```
obj.BeginInvoke(
    Sub()
        'do something'
    End Sub
)
```

The snippets look very different to me, especially because the `(Action) (() =>` part is missing completely. Is this the correct way to use `BeginInvoke` in VB.NET?

---

this is **not** a duplicate of [How to use BeginInvoke C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388136/how-to-use-begininvoke-c-sharp) because the question and every answer uses C# (if any programming language is used). C#-code doesn't help much when you are unsure about if you used the correct VB.NET syntax.

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Lambdas and Anonymous methods are one of the things that look VERY different between C# and VB.NET.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use BeginInvoke C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388136/how-to-use-begininvoke-c-sharp)

Comment: @Matt why should this be a duplicate if this question is about VB.NET syntax and the duplicate target uses C#?

Comment: *Possible* duplicate - it explains exactly what Action is and why it is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(Action)` just casts the lambda to an `Action`, which isn't needed in VB.NET. The `Sub()` lambda is all you need.

You have got the correct conversion.

Although note that `BeginInvoke()` must be followed by `EndInvoke()`, otherwise you will get thread leaks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `(Action) (() =>` doesn't return anything so `Sub` in VB.Net is equivalent. It'd be a Func in C# if it did return something.

Comment: I believe they were wondering about why the cast is necessary in C#, while it isn't in VB.

Comment: Oh ok, I see what you're saying its because VB.Net implicitly casts